# Temperature unit conversion in grafana

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating, grafana-variable

Is there a way to convert temperature from Celcius to farenheit and vice versa using grafana.
I tried manipulating `f(y)` value but I'm looking more for drop down user control to achieve this.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Use Sql query , now the `temp_f` will be your temperature in Fahrenheit.

```
select dt_created AS "time",
temperature, 
humidity, 
((temperature * 1.8) + 32) AS temp_f, 
from my_sensor ORDER BY dt_created
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Query section you can use a script. Click the Options button and in the Script field paste this:

```
((_value * 1.8) + 32)
```